# Add a xib multiple times to one UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xib, nib

Maybe it is the wrong idea completely to use the same xib multiple times in one viewcontroller, but it looked in some way better than creating an x amount of views with the same labels and the same buttons.. 
And of course some fun with xibs:)

To give you a quick impression of what I achieved so far:

[image]

In the class belonging to the xib, I created a delegate so I could catch a button press in my main view controller.

```
import UIKit

protocol TimerViewDelegate : class {
    func timerButtonTapped(buttonState : NSInteger)
}

class TimerView: UIView {

    var delegate : TimerViewDelegate?
    var currentButtonState = 0

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TimerView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton) {
        if currentButtonState == 0{
            currentButtonState = 1
        } else{
            currentButtonState = 0
        }
        self.delegate?.timerButtonTapped(currentButtonState)
    }
}
```

I know it is not super fancy stuff, but at the moment I'm only evaluating if its any use to do this at all.

In my main view controller I registered outlets for the xibs in a way like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerView1 : TimerView!
@IBOutlet weak var timerView2 : TimerView!
@IBOutlet ...
```

And in viewDidLoad():

```
self.timerView1.delegate = self
self.timerView2.delegate = self
self...
```

Later I can catch the button presses in the following method:

```
func timerButtonTapped(buttonState: NSInteger) {
    println("button press from nib, with state \(buttonState)")
}
```

From here it does make a difference if I press the button from the top xib or another one, since they keep track of their own buttonstate.
But how can I distinguish the different xibs from each other like this?

I can give the xibs themselves a tag, but I don't know if that has any use. Also talking to their labels from my main view, will have a simular problem..

Even if this is a completely wrong approach of using xibs, I'm still interested how to solve this.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: So the question is just how to identify each of the different view that you load from the XIB, because it is loaded multiple times and added into multiple different container views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have your solution already, you just need to improve your protocol method specification, basically by adding the `TimerView` that is passing on the button press.

(compare to a delegate protocol like `UITableViewDelegate`, where the table view always passes itself...)

So, something like:

```
protocol TimerViewDelegate : class {
    func timerButtonTapped(sender: TimerView, buttonState : NSInteger)
}
```

and then the delegate can find out which `TimerView` is associated and do something with it.

Incidentally, it's likely best to store the `TimerView` instances in an array, sorted in some way, so that you can easily access the details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added the `TimerView` to the protocol and changed the delegate call in the `buttonTapped` method to:
`self.delegate?.timerButtonTapped(self, buttonState: currentButtonState)`

Now in my main view controller, I can distinguish the xibs by tags:
`if sender.tag == 1 { .. } ` within the improved `timerButtonTapped`method!

But I have the feeling there is a more neat method to separate the xibs then by tags, but this was the only thing I could extract from the `sender` so quickly..

Comment: You'd need to give more details about what you're doing when the button it tapped to get more info about a better solution than using the `tag`. Generally it would be to add a `property` to your `TimerView` that you can set with the info you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag property safely. Apple documentation says:

> An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.